# Elastic Search - Apply appropriate analyser to accurate result

Tags: elasticsearch, token, elastic-stack, tokenize

I am new in Elastic Search. I would like to apply any analyser that satisfy below search.
Lets take an example.
Suppose I have entered below text in a document

1. I am walking now
2. I walked to Ahmedabad
3. Everyday I walk in the morning
4. Anil walks in the evening.
5. I am hiring candidates
6. I hired candidates
7. Everyday I hire candidates
8. He hires candidates

Now when I search with

1. text "walking"
   result should be [walking, walked, walk, walks]
2. text "walked"
   result should be [walking, walked, walk, walks]
3. text "walk"
   result should be [walking, walked, walk, walks]
4. text "walks"
   result should be [walking, walked, walk, walks]

Same result should also for hire.

1. text "hiring"
   result should be [hiring, hired, hire, hires]
2. text "hired"
   result should be [hiring, hired, hire, hires]
3. text "hire"
   result should be [hiring, hired, hire, hires]
4. text "hires"
   result should be [hiring, hired, hire, hires]

Thank You,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [stemmer token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stemmer-tokenfilter.html)

> Stemming is the process of reducing a word to its root form. This ensures variants of a word match during a search.
>
> For example, walking and walked can be stemmed to the same root word:
> walk. Once stemmed, an occurrence of either word would match the other
> in a search.

**Mapping**

```
PUT index36
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title":{
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }, 
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [ "stemmer" ,"lowercase"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Analyze**

```
GET index36/_analyze
{
  "text": ["walking", "walked", "walk", "walks"],
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
}
```

**Result**

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "walk",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 7,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "walk",
      "start_offset" : 8,
      "end_offset" : 14,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 101
    },
    {
      "token" : "walk",
      "start_offset" : 15,
      "end_offset" : 19,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 202
    },
    {
      "token" : "walk",
      "start_offset" : 20,
      "end_offset" : 25,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 303
    }
  ]
}
```

All the four words produce same token "walk". So any of these words would match the other in a search.

Comment: You are right it return walk, But when I used search query, it return only walk, My expectation is [walking, walked, walk, walks]. I used below query                                                                                             GET index36/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      
      "title": {
        "query": "walking"
        , "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
      
    }
  }
}

Comment: you need to apply analyzer to your field in mapping. It is not needed in search query. PUT index36
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title":{
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }, 
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [ "stemmer" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: @ankurpatel If you are looking just for stemming then usage of stemmer is fine. If you also need other functionalities like stop words then you can explore english language analyzer as other answer mentions

Comment: @ankurpatel if you are only looking for stemming jaspreet chahals answer is everything you need, if you are alson looking for stop-words, elastic ha built-in word-filter check out my answer

Answer (score 1):

What you are searching for is a language analyzer, see the documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.14/analysis-lang-analyzer.html)

An Word anaylzer always consists of an word-tokenizer and a word-filter as the example below shows.

```
PUT /english_example
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "english_stop": {
          "type":       "stop",
          "stopwords":  "_english_" 
        },
        "english_keywords": {
          "type":       "keyword_marker",
          "keywords":   ["example"] 
        },
        "english_stemmer": {
          "type":       "stemmer",
          "language":   "english"
        },
        "english_possessive_stemmer": {
          "type":       "stemmer",
          "language":   "possessive_english"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "rebuilt_english": {
          "tokenizer":  "standard",
          "filter": [
            "english_possessive_stemmer",
            "lowercase",
            "english_stop",
            "english_keywords",
            "english_stemmer"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can now use the analyzer in your index-mapping like this:

```
{ mappings": {
        "myindex": {
            "properties": {
                "myField": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "analyzer": "rebuilt_english"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Remember to use a match query in order to query full-text.